# Android Out Of Memory Error, Loading Random Images In To One Image View

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory, drawable

I can't quite understand how to achieve what I want. I'm trying to load a random image in to an image view from the drawables folder. I do this by grabbing a reference to all the drawables and placing the id into an int array. I than randomly choose a number between zero and the max array length and populate the imageview with that image.

The problem occurs when I rotate the screen too much, rather when too many random images have been loaded into memory i'm guessing, because an out of memory exception is thrown.

I have tried to recycle the after usage, but if I pull that image back up again i get a trying to reuse recycled bitmap error.

Questions Activity

```
package com.example.hip_hoptrivia;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuestionsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private JSONObject dataBase = null;
    private JSONArray triviaQuestions = null;
    private int currentQuestion = 0, currentDrawable;
    //setup random question images
    private int[] questionImages = new int[] {R.drawable.boswell_cheo_mural, R.drawable.buddha, R.drawable.dq,
    R.drawable.equipment, R.drawable.graffiti, R.drawable.huge_image, R.drawable.rappers, R.drawable.spray_paint,
    R.drawable.wza};

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "questiondata.txt";
    private static final String TAG_QUESTION = "Question";
    private static final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";
    private static final String TAG_INFO = "Info";
    private static final String TAG_TRIVIA = "Trivia";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);
        createData();
        createQuestion();
        buttonSetup();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

/*        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.randomImage);
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = null;
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.questions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        if(MyUtilities.NavigateActionItems( this , item))
            return true;
        else
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    private void createData(){

        String result = MyUtilities.parseLocalFile(this , FILE_NAME);

        if( result != null ){
            try{
                dataBase = new JSONObject( result );
                triviaQuestions = dataBase.getJSONArray(TAG_TRIVIA);

            }catch( JSONException e ){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else{
            Log.e("Parsing", "coudln't extract");
        }


    }

    private void createQuestion(){
        try{
            JSONObject s = triviaQuestions.getJSONObject(currentQuestion);
            String question = s.getString(TAG_QUESTION);

            //Clear Input Text
            EditText userInputEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
            userInputEditText.setText("");

            //Place Question Text
            TextView questionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.currentQuestion);
            questionTextView.setText(question);

            //Create random image that goes with text
            ImageView randomImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.randomImage);
            //Random number such that [Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))]
            currentDrawable = (int)(Math.random() * ((questionImages.length-1) + 1));
            randomImage.setImageResource(questionImages[currentDrawable]);


        }catch( JSONException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkAnswer(){
        try{
            JSONObject s = triviaQuestions.getJSONObject(currentQuestion);
            String answer = s.getString(TAG_ANSWER);
            EditText userInputEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
            String userAnswer = userInputEditText.getText().toString();


            //check if input is correct
            if( answer.equalsIgnoreCase(userAnswer)){
                ++currentQuestion;
                createQuestion();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }catch( JSONException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void buttonSetup(){
        Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //On input check if correct answer
                checkAnswer();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Layout File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hip_hoptrivia.QuestionsActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/userInput"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="115dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/userInput"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/randomImage"
        android:layout_above="@+id/currentQuestion"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as out of memory error can be a serious problem when displaying images, you need to refer properly about [Displaying Bitmaps Effeciently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Secondly

`I have tried to recycle the after usage, but if I pull that image back up again i get a trying to reuse recycled bitmap error.`

you should use

```
((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
```

Before changing to a new image.

Now this won't work if you are trying to swap an image you already recycled. Hence you'll get

```
 Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap error
```

In your `onDestroy()` you can try

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

Replace `imageView` with your `ImageView` name.Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems just adding the imageView.setImageDrawable(null) fixes the problem. I presume that it keeps the operating system from maintaing the reference to the image as it's switched and in thus flagging it for gc. Thank you so much! I would think by switching out the reference to the drawable that it would than lose the reference to the old image. As always in computing though, it seems you have to be explicit.

Comment: You got it absolutely right about the gc. If this answer solved your problem please accept the answer by clicking on the "right mark" just to the left side of the answer.By accepting the answer, it will help anyone else who visits this question.

Comment: In SO never forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.If you really liked the answer you can also upvote it by clicking on the "UP" symbol.